# Add Sum to dynamic range in specific column with vba macro excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write an Excel Macro that sums up the values of the cells above in a certain column, e.g. column "C". The first Row is always 5 but the number of rows that comes below that is varying. The code needs to select the cell in the last row and then sum up the values above, e.g. (=SUM(C5:C?)) in that cell.

Here is what I already have from code but I have trouble specifiying the second last cell in the column, which is the last cell that is going to be included in the sum:

```
With ThisWorkbook
Set wsDestination = .Worksheets("Overview")

End With

FirstRow = Rows(5).EntireRow
lastRow = wsDestination.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("Overview").Select
wsDestination.Cells(lastRow, "C").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(FirstRowC:(C& LastRow).Offset(-1,0))"
```

Can someone explain to me how to specify this? Thanks

Comment: `"=SUM(C5:C" & LastRow & ")"`... though you need to write the formula in the next row under last row.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I need to insert the formula in the last used row, as this is a row for totals.

Comment: That would mean you are overwriting data. In that case, use `LastRow - 1` in the formula.

Comment: it gives me a expected: end of statement error ```"=SUM(C5:C"& LastRow-1&")"``` when I put this

Comment: You've got the spaces wrong... should be a space before and after each `&`.